# How do I pass an object 2d array (x,y) position into an int

Tags: arrays, string, object, methods, int

I need to pass an object array at a certain position to an int. For example:

```
 private Object[][] singleplay = {{"#","Name","Score"},{"1","----------","10"},{"2","----------","20"}};

private int getnum1;
private int getnum2;
```

Here, I need to take the third position of the object array of each row. Example:

```
getnum1 = singleplay[1][2] // So getnum1 will be 10
getnum2 = singleplay[2][2] // getnum2 will be 20.
```

So I need the Int from the **3rd "x" position of each 2d "y" position**.

Comment: What code have you tried and what didn't work about it?

Comment: All I need to do is pass a position from the object to an int. I'm trying to make a score table. The object will always be changed when player enters his name, and gets his score. I need to organize the score/players from highest to lowest.

Comment: So I say again, what code have you written to achieve this and what didn't work?

Comment: i dont get your question... That part where you pass object to int doesnt work.l i need help with that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it. Also, `Object[][]` isn't right.

```
private String[][] singleplay = {{"#","Name","Score"},{"1","----------","10"},{"2","----------","20"}};

/**
 * Returns the score.
 *
 * @param id
 *        The index of the entry in the array table.
 *
 * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 *         When the destination relative position is out of bounds.
 *
 * @return The score, 0 if it's not an integer.
 */
int getScore(int id) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    // Our destination is the third element of the id th
    // first-dimensional array element:
    final String scoreRaw=singleplay[id][2];
    // Try to convert it to an actual score.
    return scoreRaw.matches("^-?\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(scoreRaw) : 0;
}
```