# NumberFormatException - how to get the result and suppress the exception?

Tags: java, string, exception

I want to use the result of the conversion. Can I do that?

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a.getText());

int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b.getText()); 

c.setText(String.valueOf(num1+num2));
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you're trying to achieve amd what your problem is.

Comment: this question does not show a minimal understanding of neither the language it concerns (Java) nor the exception paradigm itself. OP, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ first, instead of bugging people on SO

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Wrap entire code in `try` block:

```
try {
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a.getText());

    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b.getText()); 

    c.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2));
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    // Ignore?

    // Handle?
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### 2. Use a `try`-`catch` block on method invocation:

```
int num1;
try {
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(a.getText());
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    // Ignore?

    // Handle?
    a.setText(0);
    num1 = 0;
}
```

#### 3. V[a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643013/3622940)lidate `String` before parsing:

```
int num1 = a.getText().matches("-?\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(a.getText()) : 0 /* Arbitrary Default Value */;
```

Any of these three options may work; the particular choice should depends on what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't say "ignore" is the good choice here - the exception is thrown explicitly to allow you to handle invalid input case.

Comment: @vaxquis "Ignore" in this case allows defaulting to initialized value.

Comment: and how would you distinguish the initial value from *the very same value inputed as String parameter*? there's no way to do that. That exactly why exceptions are provided in Java, and ignoring that is a serious OOP/design-by-contract abuse; either initialize `int num1` in the `try` scope, so that it *can't* be used outside, and place business logic in `try` block - or provide a flag to distinguish the regular and exceptional case... the 1st solution is C++/C#/Java-like, 2nd solution is for C-style programming. If OP asks about Java, the paradigm itself is clear.

Comment: @vaxquis title explicitly mentions: "_suppress the exception_". I agree this may not be effective paradigm for program design as well. But it's to match the question.

Comment: the title mentions *suppress the exception* **because I edited it to that** *chuckle chuckle*. OP is clearly a newbie, without any understanding of neither OOP, exceptions nor Java. that's exactly why I think we should feed him with standards-compliant solutions, not kludges, tricks or workarounds.

Comment: @vaxquis Oh. Well in that case, will add variations.

Comment: thanks, this makes the answer complete. the only thing I edited is the placement of brace vs the catch and the exception's name; as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html, the usual idiom is to place `catch` on the same line as `}`, separated by a space, and to name the exception `ex` or `e` for brevity and simplicity - since it's done by convention, it's not ambiguous in this case.

Comment: @vaxquis Thanks. I'm used to having new lines for `catch` as my Eclipse formatter has that setting enabled and [the standards guideline for a project I contribute to enforces newlines for `catch`](https://github.com/mcMMO-Dev/mcMMO/blob/master/standards.md).

Comment: I've checked the guidelines for mcMMO, and while most of them are very reasonable and I'd agree with most of them wholeheartedly, "Newlines before an else, else if, catch, and finally statement" is quite strange for a Java project; the main reason for the guidelines is to have a consistent feel - and all common Java code, libraries included, use the *brace on same line* idiom - making mcMMO inconsistent with it - the exact line `} catch (RuntimeException ex) {` is taken straight from Java library source code (JDK `src.zip`), you seldom (if ever) find any other typing style there.

Answer (score 0):

The only result is the `Exception` you're already getting. It tells you that the function was unable to determine a result based on your input. E.g.: `Integer.parseInt("a")` will raise a `NumberFormatException` because `"a"` isn't commonly recognized as a number; `Integer.parseInt(" 42")` will raise a `NumberFormatException` because `" 42"` isn't fully numeric. You can of course implement something like

```
public static int parseIntOrFallback(String text, int fallback) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return fallback;
    }
}
```

or try to salvage the input by e.g. calling [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) or with your own parsing. All three are very specific to an individual use-case, which you didn't explain in-depth.